# UIWindow subclass with UISplitViewController does not rotate

Tags: ios

Very easy problem to reproduce. Create a new Master/Detail Application iOS project, and change the AppDelegate to this:

```
import UIKit

class WindowSubclass: UIWindow { }

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

//    var window: UIWindow?
    var window: WindowSubclass? = { WindowSubclass(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) }()
```

Run on iPad simulator/device and start rotating. If the device was in portrait mode when the application was launched, it'll rotate fine. If the application launched in landscape mode, it'll quickly get messed up.

[image: iPad simulator showing improperly rotated view]

I suspect my problem is in the getter for the `window` property, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. The line I used seems to be the canonical way of doing it.

Based on answers to similar questions, I have ensured that the window's `rootViewController` is set to the `UISplitViewController` and the split view controller's `shouldAutorotate()` returns `true`, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 'maybe' solution.

It seems that when the `window` property is accessed, and the `WindowSubclass` instantiated, the screen doesn't really know what orientation it is.

If you add `window!.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` in `application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` then it sorts itself out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason this is happening is because it's the `UIViewController` which launches the app. On all other `UIViewControllers`, my subclass `UIWindow` rotates fine when I set its `rootViewController` as the `UIViewController` that it's being presented on. I'm not sure if this is the intended behavior for some reason or if it's a bug in iOS.